# Google Instance ssh using `gcompute`, different user name

Tags: google-app-engine, ssh, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, instance

I am able to connect to my instance using `gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone us-east1-b`.

Once I log-in, I see this: `wendy@instance-1`. And when I `ls`, I don't see my files.

If I ssh using the online webpage[image]

I seethe following:

`randy@instance-1`. And when I `ls`, I do see my files.

Ok. Both are under the same google email account, and has the same `Internal IP: 10.142.0.2`

My question is, how do I log-in using `gcloud` command, into `randy@instance-1`?

Answer (score 3):

You can also specify a user when using the [gcloud compute ssh](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) command:

```
gcloud compute ssh [USER@]INSTANCE
```

If you omit a user, the default one will be used, which is from the environment.

Comment: You can also change the username for SSH from browser by clicking on the Settings>Change Linux Username option. You can refer to [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#login_username) for details.

Answer (score 0):

Open a command prompt / shell. The execute the following command to list the users that are configured for the CLI:

`gcloud auth list`

The account that is the current account has the asterisk in the left column. If that is the wrong account, or to just make sure, re-authenticate:

`gcloud auth login`.

Use the correct credentials to login to `Google Accounts`.

Now you will be able to `gcloud compute ssh` and be logged in with the correct user credentials.

I wrote an article on Google account configurations that goes deeper into how multiple credentials are managed by the CLI and SDK.

[Understanding Gcloud Configurations](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-understanding-gcloud-configurations/)

Comment: I think I got the correct Google account login, its the same account, and there is only one account when I do `gcloud auth list`

Comment: What is the name of the Google Account that you are authenticating with. That will determine the user name when you SSH into the instance.

Comment: It looks like `wendy`, is my macbook's username, and that `randy`, is the my google account's user name...

Comment: Authenticate with the randy account when you execute `gcloud auth login` or open Chrome and authenticate with randy. Also log out of the wendy account in Chrome. You are mixing up your credentials.

Comment: You can also associate a user when using [gcloud compute ssh user@instance](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh)

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that Google automatically creates and adds a user to the newly created VMs using your Gmail name & surname as username in the name_surname format. You can see this in google `cloud console -> compute engine -> metadata -> ssh keys`

Google manages the private key for this account so I'm not aware of any way of connecting to this account other than the cloud console.

However you can still access to your files after you login with `gcloud` command. Just do `sudo su` and you will become root user. Then you can copy files from `/home/wendy` to `/home/randy`.

Answer (score 0):

you do have two option
Fisrt is to authenticate with the right user account by running the gcloud command

> gcloud auth login

And use the "randy" user account in this case, then use the gcloud command normally to ssh.

> gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone us-east1-b

Second option is to SSH directly with the appropriate username from this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh) by running the gcloud command below.

> gcloud compute ssh [USER@]INSTANCE [--zone=ZONE]

One thing, you could easily recover or copy your files by switching to the root user (you need just to run the command line "sudo su -" or "sudo -i")

Answer (score 0):

If you're already logged in, and maybe don't have the option to choose a username during login (e.g. when using the iOS app), you can also use

```
sudo su [username]
```

to switch the username from an existing session.